# Slowing cooker hood fan on lowest setting with resistive series load (or alternative)

Tags: motor, diy

My cooker hood has 3 settings, and the low setting is very powerful.

I want to make it less powerful to reduce the (high) noise but still provide some extraction.

I have dismantled the circuit to figure out what could be done and have drawn it (crudely) below, with resistors representing the motor windings as measured by a multimeter (resistive only  not reactance).

The motor (in blue) is a 180 W, 230 VAC motor with 4 connections. Neutral and the 3 taps provided which the switch unit connects to the live.

[image: Cooker hood circuit]

It seems that the lowest power could still be >60% of max power, but I want it to be more like 25% of max. Having 60%, 80% and 100% seems a bit pointless to me!

Can I add a load resistor into the circuit (in the red highlighted area) to reduce the motor speed?
Do I need a reactive element?
What is a suitable component considering power dissipation and voltage rating?

Answer (score 0):

The ohmic resistance of the motor windings are irrelevant -- different windings are used to change the *phase* of the rotating magnetic field. More sensible would be to put a motor phase-control in series with the 230 VAC mains. Do *not* use an ordinary light dimmer, because it might not commutate with an inductive load. A ceiling fan speed control might work, depending on the motor in the hood.

**N.B.** Do not mount the speed control where it will get hot from the cooker.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware ohmix resistance wasn't relevant but it was the only way I could measure windings between the connections. I've found this better diagram although I can't see the capacitor in my setup https://community.home-assistant.io/t/making-a-dumb-cooker-hood-smart/142537/19 . Is my motor also an autotransformer? Since I want just a permeant speed reduction can I some how "extend" it with an inductor/transformer for the largest tap?

Answer (score 0):

Resistors waste lots of power .If this is inconvenient try inductive reactance .I have used old flourescent lamp ballasts .Much less heating for a given speed reduction .You could  also consider an autotransformer with various taps ,If you test on a variac you will get an idea of what your autotransformer voltage should be .

Comment: Thanks for the idea about the Magnetic balast. What about something like https://www.bradfieldwholesale.com/product/b42-ballast-choke-magnetic-58w-65w-5ft/14984/0 or https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/352310163784 ?